# What is the difference between these code snippets of graph complementing?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory

I have used this code snippet for taking complement of my graph -

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            graph[i][j] = 1 - graph[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

This gives a Wrong Answer . But when I replace it with the following snippet, it get's accepted-

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        if(graph[i][j] == 1)
            graph[i][j] = 0;
        else if(i != j)
            graph[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure the difference between these two.

Comment: How graph[][] is initialized, is it initialized with 0 all over or something else ?

Comment: It is initialized with 0 at diagonals and at rest if there is an edge between i and j then garph[i][j]=graph[j][i]=1

Comment: Interesting can you pass a link to that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
if(i!=j)
{
   graph[i][j]= 1-graph[i][j];
}
```

its not the same as this:

```
if(graph[i][j] == 1)    graph[i][j] = 0;
else if(i != j)         graph[i][j] = 1;
```

In the first one you're modifying a matrix to be 1-N everywhere but in the diagonal.

Given this matrix:

```
 1 1 0
 1 1 0 
 1 1 0
```

The first code will give you:

```
 1 0 0
 0 1 0 
 0 0 0
```

The seocnd one will give you:

```
 0 0 1
 0 0 1 
 0 0 0
```

Comment: The diagonal of my matrix is initialized to 0 and I want no modification in it.

Comment: Your second algorithm converts all diagonals 1 to 0, else leave them untouched

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if(i != j || graph[i][j] == 1) {
            graph[i][j] = 1 - graph[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

You just didn't add the code `graph[i][j] == 1`

Comment: But I want the 0's to be 1's and 1's to be 0's except the diagonal elements unchanged?

Comment: Wait @Amisha Bansal..You have written the code (which worked correctly) as `if(graph[i][j] == 1) graph[i][j] = 0;` which means no matter what the value of i and j if the value in graph[i][j] is 1 you are making it 0. So if the diagonal element is 1 then it will be made 0. Please make sure you are clear with what kind of output you expect!  @Aschab also mentioned that diagonal elements will be 0 if graph[i][j] = 1!